# REGEXP valid on not alphanumeric and not space, '-' characters

Tags: mysql, regex

I want to find only non alphanumeric characters and only without space without '-'...

But this is not working:

```
REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z0-9/-:space:]*'
```

This regexp is valid on these data:

```
 'Test Cinema'
  'AMERICANII AU TALENT - SEZONUL 5, EPISODUL 12'
```

I dont want to find these characters, i want to find fields like this:

```
'Test Item;?!'
'LOCAL KOMBAT "FIERBE BULGARIA"'
```

How can i write a regexp which is only valid on other characters.

Comment: thank you, but this is not working, still find 'Test Cinema'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be useful to have a list of things the test should match and should not match clearly defined, as it is kind of have to guess

Try

```
1. ^.*?[^A-Za-z0-9 -]+[A-Za-z0-9 -]*$
2. ^.*?[^A-Za-z0-9, -]+[A-Za-z0-9, -]*$
```

**1 matches** ( the first one because of the comma)

```
AMERICANII AU TALENT - SEZONUL 5, EPISODUL 12
Test Item;?!
LOCAL KOMBAT "FIERBE BULGARIA"
```

but does not match
    Test Cinema

**2 matches**

```
Test Item;?!
LOCAL KOMBAT "FIERBE BULGARIA"
```

But does not match

```
Test Cinema
AMERICANII AU TALENT - SEZONUL 5, EPISODUL 12
```

You can play with the second one [here](http://regexr.com?31rh0) 
I had to negate the newline to make it work for the sample, but just add one test per line to see whether or not it matches

Comment: exactly what i needed, unfortunately i cant run these pattern on mysql... but work on it, thank you for the "playground" marked answer...

Answer (score 6):

The ^ needs to be inside the brackets for it to be a negation. When placed at the beginning of the regex ^ means that it should be matched at the beginning of the string.

Try this to match all non-empty, non-alphanumeric (including space and -) strings:

```
^[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]+$
```

Answer (score 4):

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]*
```

That would be what you want, I think.

By placing the `-` at the end of the `[]`, the regex knows you mean a literal `-`, and you don't need to escape it with `\`.

Edit: To match the *whole string*, use this:

```
^[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]*$
```

`^` and `$` are used to anchor the regex to the beginning and end of the string.

Comment: @czupe - Note that the dash, unescaped, must be last in the character class, else it will be interpreted as a range of characters.

Comment: thank you, but stil find, valid on 'Test Cinema', and i want a reg expression  which is only valid on [non alphanumerical characters and  non'-',  non ' ']

Comment: @czupe That's what my regex does. Do you mean that *the whole string* needs to be those?

Comment: @KendallFrey: maybe i was not clear, sorry. I want to wipe, filter field wich contains only alphanumeric characters and '-' and space... I want to get fields which contains other characters for example: '!' '?' '"' (quote) and other character.